# Fresh install of 16.04 LTS extremely slow with ATI ES1000 GPU

Tags: 16.04

I installed 16.04 on an HP DL360 G5.  It is extremely slow.  System monitor shows all four Xeon cores running between 35% and 75%.  Sorting the highest processor use to the top, in processes, shows Compiz using about 10% to 20% of the CPU.

The UI (Unity Desktop) is especially slow.  Moving a window or typing into a textbox has an incredible delay.

How do I troubleshoot this?  Any ideas about what's wrong?

Update:  I've discovered that the high CPU usage (35% to 75% per core) only occurs when when I'm on the resources tab.  If I go to the processes tab for a bit, then switch back to Resources, I can see that while I was away per core processor usage drops to near zero.

Comment: What's the GPU? Is it still slow if you install a 2D desktop environment like LXDE?

Comment: ATI ES1000.  I will try installing LXDE and see what happens!

Comment: Oh gosh... yeah, that's definitely the problem. That card has 64MB of VRAM, and it doesn't even have any sort of 3D acceleration at all. LXDE will be your friend!

Comment: SWEET!!  Thank you!!  I've installed LXDE, but have not yet figured out how to slap Unity to the side and bring LXDE into play.  All info I've Googled so far indicates there should be a menu on the logon box, that I don't have.

Comment: For others who may find this post:  I just found this:
https://wiki.lxde.org/en/Ubuntu
And am hoping it will take me in the right direction.

Comment: See this image, it shows where to click on the login screen: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hDndL.jpg

Comment: Thank you.  That little icon wasn't there until I installed some additional stuff (https://wiki.lxde.org/en/Installation).  Just installing LXDE did not put it there.

Comment: What's the performance like with LXDE?

Comment: It works perfectly now.

Comment: I would love to give you credit...yes.

Comment: I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, the issue turned out to be that the OP's video card had only 64MB of VRAM, and didn't even have any hardware 3D acceleration at all.

Unity being a 3D desktop environment, it absolutely brought the GPU to its knees.

---

The solution was to install a 2D desktop environment, such as LXDE.